# Escaping environment variables in Spring Cloud Config properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-config

I just setup a Spring Cloud Config server and have an application.yml file that should contain:

```
hostname: ${MY_ENV_VARIABLE}
```

When I pull that config file, the placeholder gets expanded before being sent instead of being sent to the application so that the *application* can expand it.

How do I either make Spring Cloud Config server *stop* expanding environment placeholders in the configuration files being served or *escape* the placeholders?

Comment: Does the value of ${MY_ENV_VARIABLE} exist in any yml file in config server ?

Comment: Yes. It was my assumption that the config files _served_ by the config server were separated from the ones _used_ by the config server.

Answer (score 0):

This question is due to ignorance on my part. When you request the configuration as Spring Boot does, e.g., https://config-server:8888/myapp/myprofile/master, then you get the JSON that describes the configuration and NO PROPERTY EXPANSION OCCURS. But, when you test the configuration by requesting it as a YAML file, e.g., https://config-server:888/myapp-myprofile.yaml, then property expansion occurs before the YAML file is displayed.

So, for my purposes, this works fine. I just need to be aware of it when checking that configurations are valid.